# Weird behavior in Python

Tags: python, list

I wrote a simple program to translate DNA to RNA. Basically, you input a string, it separates the string into characters and sends them to a list, shifts the letter and returns a string from the resulting list. This program correctly translates a to u, and to to a, but does not change g to c and c to g.

This is the program:

```
def trad(x):

    h=[]
    for letter in x:
        h.append(letter)
    for letter in h:
        if letter=="a":
            h[h.index(letter)]="u"
            continue
        if letter=="t":
            h[h.index(letter)]="a"
            continue
        if letter=="g":
            h[h.index(letter)]="c"
            continue
        if letter=="c":
            h[h.index(letter)]="g"
            continue
    ret=""
    for letter in h:
        ret+=letter
    return ret

while True:
    stry=raw_input("String?")
    print trad(stry)
```

Now, just altering the program by not iterating over elements, but on positions, it works as expected. This is the resulting code:

```
def trad(x):
    h=[]
    for letter in x:
        h.append(letter)
    for letter in xrange (0, len(h)):
        if h[letter]=="a":
            h[letter]="u"
            continue
        if h[letter]=="t":
            h[letter]="a"
            continue
        if h[letter]=="g":
            h[letter]="c"
            continue
        if h[letter]=="c":
            h[letter]="g"
            continue
    ret=""
    for letter in h:
        ret+=letter
    return ret

while True:
    stry=raw_input("String?")
    print trad(stry)
```

Why does this strange behaviour occur, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: You never explain the issue with your first set of code.

Comment: I've edited it to explain the issue sorry on that

Comment: the indentation thing I'll leave implied (sorry, lazy :p)

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: You know, it is easy enough to fix indentation like that for a new poster.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido, that attitude will not help you round here. It's easy to fix the indentation and it'll help future visitors if you do. Having obviously incorrect code helps no one. (Ctrl+k is intent by 4 spaces. De-indent `def()` and then indent everything.) It's okay to say "I don't know how" but I can't be bothered won't necessarily go down that well...

Comment: @SebastianGarrido I'm tempted to delete my answer - you know, *leave it implied*. If you can't be bothered to format your question, why should we bother to answer your question?

Comment: Particularly when indentation in Python, unlike some other languages, is of *paramount* importance to the program's functionality.

Comment: I didn't think my answer would spur such controversy. I am sorry. Let me explain: I did not know how to fix the indentation problem, so I left it like that. I think is okay now. Sorry for bothering all of you.

Comment: You've got a couple of great answers. As for why your method doesn't work... h.index(letter) finds the first occurrence of the letter in the string, not the letter you are currently working on. So, you keep changing the first "g" to "c" and then back to "g" as you find "g" and "c" in the input. Same for the first "c". You'll get a few to change permanently depending on how many g's and c's are in the input.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido You are more than welcome to ask how to do it. After all, this is a site for having questions answered.

Answer (score 7):

You are going about this a much harder way than is necessary, this could easily be done using [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) - a method on `str` instances that translates instances of one character to another, which is exactly what you want:

```
import string
replacements = string.maketrans("atgc", "uacg")
while True:
    stry=raw_input("String?")
    print stry.translate(replacements)
```

This is an answer for 2.x, in 3.x, use `str.maketrans()` instead.

Comment: It's not only more difficult, it's a lot slower than using `translate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of issue you are having, but here's a simple way to do it, using a dictionary.

```
def trad(coding_strand):
    mRNA_parts = {'a': 'u', 't': 'a', 'g': 'c', 'c': 'g'}
    mRNA = ''
    for nucleotide in coding_strand: # this makes it lowercase
        mRNA += mRNA_parts[nucleotide.lower()]
    return mRNA.upper() # returns it as uppercase
```

I have it returned as uppercase because, generally, nucleotides in DNA/RNA are written in uppercase.

I also revised your method... It's better to iterate through the indices themselves; then you don't have to do `l.index(elem)`.

```
def trad(coding_strand):
    mRNA = []
    for index in range(len(coding_strand)):
       nucleotide = coding_strand[index].upper()
       if nucleotide == 'A':
           mRNA.append('U')
       elif nucleotide == 'T':
           mRNA.append('A')
       elif nucleotide == 'C':
           mRNA.append('G')
       elif nucleotide == 'G':
           mRNA.append('C')
    ret = ''
    for letter in mRNA:
        ret += mRNA
    print ret
```

I don't suggest using a string and adding on to it nor using a list; a list comprehension is much more effective.

Here's a semi-one-liner, courtesy of BurhanKhalid:

```
def trad(coding_strand): 
    mRNA_parts = {'A': 'U', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}
    return ''.join([mRNA_parts[nucleotide] for nucleotide in coding_strand.upper()])
```

A complete one-liner:

```
def trade(coding_strand, key={'A': 'U', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}): ''.join(return [key[i] for i in coding_strand.upper()])
```

Some references:

- [Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: `return ''.join(mRNA_parts[nucleotide] for nucleotide in coding_strand).upper()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I thought of that, but I figured it's best to explain it in in a simple manner. I'll include that, though.

Comment: Yeah, constructing a string through repeated concatenation is sub-optimal and may cause severe performance problems on some platforms. `str.join()` and [a list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) is a better solution.

Comment: -1.  A few problems.  `for nucleotide.lower() in coding_strand:` is not legal Python.  Also, building a string a single character at a time is a Python anti-pattern.  Finally, why convert to lower case then back to upper?  Seems a pointless round trip.  Just make sure it's all upper.